# Mediaplayer class slow

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I created an application to play an online radio and when using the MediaPlayer class, I noticed that the time between clicking the button and the radio start playing is very long (it takes at least 35 seconds).
One way to solve this problem was to use a WebView and use HTML5, but as we say here in Brazil, this is a gambiarra (workaround).
Is there a way to minimize this time or recommend some other component to use in the application?

Comment: The time also matters with your own network connection!

Comment: The problem is not in the connection, because when the solution is based on HTML5, it works perfectly.

Comment: Ohh then may be its buffering!

Comment: Is there a way to minimize this time or recommend some other component to use in the application?

Comment: It may depend how you are using MediaPlayer - it would helot share your code extract